# Can files survive partition table and file system recreation?

Tags: parted, ext2

By `GNU parted` I created new DOS partition table, one partition and by `mkfs.ext2` ext2 file system on that partition. I copied some files to that partition. After that I again created new DOS partition table, one partition and ext2 file system on the same HDD. When I mounted this partition some files still was there. Is it possible that files survive partition and file system recreation?

Comment: Can you be more clear ?

Comment: I think you didn't make the new filesystem exactly where it was, but after that disk area with overlapping. But the non-overlapping part of the old disk area is still marked as another new partition. So you just mounted a broken ext2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible if you delete and re-create your partition from the exact same sector. The system does not a "full format" when you create your file system. By the way, you can do the same to extend a partition. Delete and recreate it starting from the same sector and ending on a further one

Comment: But wouldn't mkfs.ext2 mark all the filesystem blocks of those files as available? And the inode table should be cleared.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure. In my case I found files back on an XFS disk coming from a RAID array and after creating a new partition table, partition and mkfs.xfs.